# Why if the rank of matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}2x&2y&0\\1&0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ is less than $2$,then $x=y=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The rank of matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}2x&2y&0\\1&0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ is less than $2$ if and only if $x=y=0$.

I can't understand the only if part, that is why "if the rank of matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}2x&2y&0\\1&0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ is less than $2$,then $x=y=0$"?

Comment: what do you know about rank of a matrix? Is it somehow related to determinant of submatrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to understand in the negative. "If either $x$ or $y$ is nonzero, the rank of the matrix is 2." You can work that out, I think.

Comment: Sir, I can work out this for x and y fixed a number, but can't for the general form. How to do it?

Comment: @Sush Try to prove the general lemma that vectors $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$ are linearly independent if and only if $c_1v_1, \dotsc, c_nv_n$ are linearly independent, provided $c_i \neq 0$ for all $i$. This is easier than it sounds. Remember that you can use any scalar to make a linear combination of vectors, so it doesn't really matter if your vector is already multiplied by a nonzero scalar...you can always get whatever combination you had before by just multiplying by the inverse of that scalar.

Comment: @Sush Proof of one direction: Suppose $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$ are linearly independent. Suppose for contradiction that $c_1v_1, \dotsc, c_nv_n$ are linearly dependent. Then there exists a linear combination $$a_1(c_1v_1) + \dotsb + a_n(c_nv_n)=0,$$ where not all $a_i$ are zero. Then $$(a_1c_1)v_1 + \dotsb + (a_nc_n)v_n=0$$ is a linear combination of $v_i$, and some $a_ic_i\neq 0$. This is a contradiction, because $v_i$ linearly independent. The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of your matrix, 2x3, suggest that the highest possible rank can be 2. The bottom row of your matrix shows that the smallest possible rank has to be 1. Now in order for the rank of this matrix to be less than 2 one row has to be comprised entirely of zeros. Note that this is impossible for the bottom row. That implies the top row must be entirely comprised of zeros. Which can only occur when what happens?

You should be able to get it from here.

Comment: "Now in order for the rank of this matrix to be less than 2 one row has to be comprised entirely of zeros." That is not true. The rows could be multiples of each other; for instance, the top row could be a multiple of $\begin{matrix} 1&0&1\end{matrix}$.

Comment: Yes but that is not possible with this particular matrix. Since the entry in the upper right spot is zero.

Comment: Eric is correct that in general rank is determined by the matrix reduction. So if this was a more general question my approach would not have worked.